# How to trigger Update of an AWS Cloudformation stack when an object is uploaded to an S3 bucket?

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-cloudformation, amazon-sns, auto-update

We have a list of AWS Lambda functions that are deployed using AWS CloudFormation and their code is placed in an Amazon S3 bucket.

We update the Lambda code by uploading the latest code to S3 and running the `update-stack` command which has an S3 object version parameter. So when object version change is detected (ie: new Lambda code is uploaded to s3) we run the update stack command and then CloudFormation deploys the new code.

I was think of automating this process by triggering the stack update when an object is uploaded to S3. Can this be done?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can **use an Amazon S3 Event to trigger an AWS Lambda function** when an object is uploaded to Amazon S3.

See: [Using AWS Lambda with Amazon S3](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/with-s3.html)

This Lambda function could then call the CloudFormation `UpdateStack()` function to update the stack. You can use your choice of language in the Lambda function.

Comment: Is it possible to execute update stack(),create stack () commands from within a lambda?Which package is to be installed to run these commands. I have heard of devs using AWS CLI inside lambdas are you referring to those or is there another way? Can you please elaborate. Thanks

Comment: There is no need to use the AWS CLI. It is intended for command-line use. Basically, you can do **absolutely everything** on AWS via programmatic calls.  See: [AWS SDKs](https://aws.amazon.com/tools/#SDKs). As an example, see [CloudFormation commands from Python](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/cloudformation.html)

Comment: Thanks a ton. Finally found out the Cloudformation client for dotnet. https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkfornet/latest/apidocs/

Comment: Be careful when using an s3 event. It will trigger the Lambda asynchronously which could result in unexpected additional Lambda invocations if it errors for whatever reason.